# Why $(\mathbb R^*, \cdot)$ isn't an ordered group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, order-theory

I don't understand why $(\mathbb R^*, \cdot)$ (group with multiplication) is not ordered ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean partially ordered group as in here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_group

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Suppose $\preceq$ was an order on $(\Bbb R^*,\cdot)$. Now let's pose the question - which is larger with respect to $\preceq$, $-1$ or $1$? If $-1\prec1$, then by multiplying both sides by $-1$ we should have $(-1)\cdot(-1)\prec1\cdot(-1)$, so $1\prec -1$, which is impossible. Similarly we cannot have $1\prec -1$, so this group cannot be totally ordered.

Answer (score 5):

I believe it's because multiplication by a negative is order reversing.  The operation is not strictly order preserving.  But if you just restrict to the positive real numbers $\Bbb R^{+}$ then it is an ordered group under multiplication.

Comment: Yes, i think so but i tried to write it out but i wasn't able; where the problem comes from ? I check all order characteristics (transitivity, ..) but don't know how to express.

Comment: You need $a<b$ to imply $ac<bc$ for all $c$.  But if $c=-1$ then it's not true.